# Getting localized messages from a jar file

Tags: jsf, jar, localization, jsf-2.2, resourcebundle

I am currently refactoring common resources (css, images & javascript) of two belonging frontend (web) projects into a separate jar file and it works perfectly fine.

Now I am trying to do the same with localized messages, but I must be missing something, as I only get the keys of the 'default' messages, without localization.

My jar file is structured like this:

```
faces-util.jar
  |--META-INF 
     |--resources
        |--css
        |--images
        |--js
```

Putting the messages files directly in the root folder (`src/main/resources`) it works, but only for the default locale (`messages.properties`). Localized message files like `messages_de.properties` are ignored.

Here is my faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
          xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
  <application>
     <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
     </locale-config>

     <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>messages</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
     </resource-bundle>

   </application>
</faces-config>
```

I tried putting `faces-config.xml` inside `/META-INF` or `/META-INF/resources` but without success.

In the web projects I have the standard config `faces-config.xml` inside `WEB-INF` and the messages properties files in `/src/main/resources`.

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody give me a hint?

Thx in advance